# Error while trying to use solana_program_test?

Tags: rust, solana-program-test

[image]

i am getting "RpcError(DeadlineExceeded)" all time.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a couple of reasons:

- In the past, if there were too many tests running, you could see this sporadically -- the most annoying one to diagnose. Since you're only running 3 tests, I doubt it's that. Be sure to upgrade to fix that.
- A program that you're trying to call isn't loaded. Rather than giving an immediate error, sometimes it'll just hang. Be sure to add all programs that you're trying to call into (along with their dependencies) with `ProgramTest::add_program`